# MySQL: добавление записей без повторов

Tags: mysql, sql

Как написать запрос чтобы повторов в столбце не было?

Например чтобы при добавлении запроса с значением Владимир в столбец Имя,
оно не добавлялось, если есть уже запись Владимир в столбце)

в SQLite я просто структуру создаю которая мешает добавлению,
а вот в MySQL я не знаю...

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm

Comment: два слова: unique index

Comment: да, спасибо. Поставил Uniq, и INSERT IGNORE INTO
как таймштамп вставит по средствам SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Пусть имеется таблица `tbl` с текстовым полем `name`, в котором должны быть только уникальные значения. Для этого удобнее всего воспользоваться уникальным индексом, добавить который в таблицу можно либо при помощи запроса

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_of_name ON tbl (name(10));
```

либо при помощи оператора `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE tbl 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_of_name (name(10));
```

После этого добавить повторяющееся значение в таблицу не получится. Если вы не хотите получать сообщения об ошибке при попытке вставки повторяющегося значения можно использовать ключевое слово `IGNORE` в операторе `INSERT`.